# SQL How to select the first actor of the current movie id and or show id who has > 0 films or shows

Tags: sql, mysql, select

Sort of new to `PHP (8.1) & SQL (Myqli)` and seriously stuck on this one. Would very much appreciate some help here.

SQL Tables are as follows:

```
$currenttvshowid='27641';

tvshow: tvshowid title

tvshow_actors: actorid actorname

tvshow_starredin: actorid tvshowid role
```

where, for instance:
$currentseriesid='27641'

**tv_shows table**

| tvshowid | title |
| --- | --- |
| 27641 | The Addams Family |
| 18644 | The Beverly Hillbillies |
| 38235 | Chico and the Man |
| 26244 | I Dream of Jeannie |
| ... | ... |

**tv_show_actors table**

| actorid | actorname |
| --- | --- |
| 47863 | Carolyn Jones |
| 20602 | John Astin |
| 40376 | Jackie Coogan |
| 20317 | Ted Cassidy |
| 18927 | Buddy Ebsen |
| 263177 | Freddie Prinze |
| 36613 | Barbara Eden |
| ... | ... |

**tv_show_starredin table**

| actorid | tvshowid | role |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 47863 | 27641 | Morticia Addams |
| 20602 | 27641 | Gomez Addams |
| 40376 | 27641 | Uncle Fester |
| 20317 | 27641 | Lurch |
| 150863 | 27641 | Grandmama |
| 150864 | 27641 | Wednesday Addams |
| 150865 | 27641 | Pugsley Addams |
| 14067 | 27641 | Cousin Itt |
| 18927 | 18644 | Jed "JD" Clampett |
| 20317 | 18644 |  |
| 263177 | 38235 | Chico Rodriguez |
| 20317 | 38235 |  |
| 36613 | 26244 | Jeannie |
| 20317 | 26244 | Habib |
| ... | ... | ... |

I would like to get the result of the other shows that actor Ted Cassidy (20317) played in based on the amount of times he's listed in the tv_show_starredin table excluding the current tv show.

| tvshowid | title |
| --- | --- |
| 18644 | The Beverly Hillbillies |
| 38235 | Chico and the Man |
| 26244 | I Dream of Jeannie |

I'm trying to get the `actorid` and `name` of the first actor from the current tvshowid who has greater than 0 shows.

Basically want to count or list how many other TV shows actor Ted Cassidy actorid (20317) played in excluding the current tvshowid (27641) if that makes any sense?

```
SELECT a.*, t.*
    FROM tv_show_actors a
    JOIN tv_show_starredin t ON a.actor_id = t.actor_id
    WHERE t.tvshow_id IN (
        SELECT tvshow_id
        FROM tv_shows
        WHERE tvshow_id = '$currentseriesid'
    ) LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Since your limit is already 1, do you really need a `select` statement in `where` clause? You can simply just do `WHERE m.movie_id = '$currentmovieid'` and for the `greater than 0 films or shows`, you can just add an `AND` statement like this `AND a.actor_id IN (
    SELECT actor_id
    FROM movie_starredin
    GROUP BY actor_id
    HAVING COUNT(movie_id) > 0
)`. Keeping the limit to 1 just to make sure.

Comment: To be more a little more specific what I'd like to be able to do is get the actor name and id who has more than more the one movie or show from the  $currentmovieid=$_GET["movieid"]; or $currentseriesid=$_GET["seriesid"];

Comment: Is this a PHP problem or a MySQL problem? Keep in mind that the query you've shared is highly vulnerable for SQL injection

Comment: A MySQL issue. How so?

Comment: Because of `tvshow_id = '$currentseriesid'`. Never include variable data directly into your queries. Read https://xkcd.com/327/ for an amusing example of what can go wrong. More trivial exploits however are more common and harder to avoid. Also your code can be unreliable - SQL can crash if the input value so happens to contain a value which is also used in SQL syntax (e.g. imagine a name field included into the SQL this way, where the user inputs `O'Brien`). Next read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537377/how-to-include-a-php-variable-inside-a-mysql-statement for how to fix it

Comment: The inclusion of a variable directly in the sql leaves your code open to sql injection. **Always** use a prepared statement when using user supplied data - in this case a GET parameter

Comment: I don't understand the task. You start with some TV show, e.g. 27641 (The Addams Family). You then select the actors of that movie, and for every actor you want to check whether they played in other TV shows and show this result? Or count in how many other TV shows they played? Or only select those actors that played in other TV shows? Or only select those actors that played in no other TV show? Or something else still?

Comment: Want to count or list how many other TV shows actor Ted Cassidy (20317) played in excluding the current tvshow id (27641) if that makes any sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Want to count or list how many other TV shows actor Ted Cassidy (20317) played in excluding the current tvshow id (27641)

So, you basically want to count all tv_show_starredin entries for the actor except for the current TV show.

```
set @actor_id = 20317;
set @current_tvshow_id = 27641;

select count(*)
from tv_show_starredin
where actor_id = @actor_id
and tvshow_id <> @current_tvshow_id;
```

This counts the roles the actor played. If you want to count a TV show only once where the actor played more than one role, use `COUNT(DISTINCT tvshow_id)`:

```
select count(distinct tvshow_id)
from tv_show_starredin
where actor_id = @actor_id
and tvshow_id <> @current_tvshow_id;
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That is exactly what I needed.